# Change case in First node in XmlDocument

Tags: c#, xml

I have this XML:

```
<Feedback>
  <Officer>Officer</Officer>
  <Answers>My text</Answers>
  <Date>20190917</Date>
</Feedback>
```

I want XML to look like this: (Lowercase first letter in main tag)

```
<feedback>
  <Officer>Officer</Officer>
  <Answers>My text</Answers>
  <Date>20190917</Date>
</feedback>
```

How to do it using `XMLDocument`? I can't access this item

Answer (score 1):

If using XmlDocument is not a hard requirement you can do it with linq fairly easily.

You can create a new XML document with the root node named how you want it then loop through the child nodes of the original and add them to your new XML object.

A simple example:

```
XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Parse("<Feedback><Officer>Officer</Officer><Answers>My text</Answers><Date>20190917</Date></Feedback>");
XDocument newDoc = new XDocument();
XElement rootElement = new XElement("feedback");
newDoc.Add(rootElement);

foreach (var node in xDocument.Root.Elements())
   {
      newDoc.Root.Add(node);
   }

Console.WriteLine(newDoc);
Console.ReadLine();
```

However here is an example using XmlDocument if you really need to use that:

```
XmlDocument oldDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDocument newXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
oldDoc.LoadXml("<Feedback><Officer>Officer</Officer><Answers>My text</Answers><Date>20190917</Date></Feedback>");

XmlElement newRoot = newXmlDoc.CreateElement("feedback");
newXmlDoc.AppendChild(newRoot);

XmlNode root = newXmlDoc.DocumentElement;

foreach (XmlNode node in oldDoc.FirstChild.ChildNodes)
{
    XmlElement elem = newXmlDoc.CreateElement(node.Name);
    elem.InnerText = node.InnerText;

    //Add the node to the document.
    root.AppendChild(elem);
}

XmlTextWriter writer = new XmlTextWriter(Console.Out);
writer.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
newXmlDoc.WriteTo(writer);
writer.Flush();
Console.WriteLine();
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can change the name directly:

```
var XML = ""; // Your XML in string

var tempDoc = new XmlDocument();
tempDoc.LoadXml(XML);
tempDoc.InnerXml = tempDoc.InnerXml.Replace("Feedback>", "feedback>");

XML = tempDoc.OuterXml;
```

This is a simple way to change the name

Do not use in other situations because various errors may arise, e.g another element may end in the same name